# how to change nicedit default color

Tags: php, html, css, textarea, nicedit

I have a textbox incorporating the nice edit [image]

after I save it the view background is black.Since the default color of text is black this will look like
[image]

I high-lightened to test if theres text. 
if i change the text color to white in the textbox to white this will be look like
[image]

 as you can see this is inappropriate.

so my question is how may I set default color is white if the backgound color in view page. 

 any comments or suggestion is well appriciated. Thanks

Comment: Whats the last button on second row?

Comment: @Alexandros upload image sir.

Comment: my bad... i thought that was "remove formatting"

Answer (score 2):

```
.nicEdit-main{
     background-color: white;
}
```

that will work..

Answer (score 0):

If you read the wiki documentation, there are a few configuration options for setting the CSS of the panel. If you specify you're own external CSS, you should be able to set the foreground and background colours there:

```
new nicEditor({externalCSS : 'mysite.css'});
```

Where mysite.css contains something like:

```
  textarea {
      background-color: white;
      color:white;
  }
```

http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/515/Configuration%20Options

Comment: alright I will try this. thank for answer, I will get back to you later sir..Thanks again